# Really cool spambot behaviour

Tags: support, spam

We have a series of spambot questions

https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/42353/automate-mac-app-store-installs-upgrades legit question off apple.se

https://superuser.com/questions/435721/automate-mac-app-store-installs-upgrades Spambot.

He's scraping questions off other sites, and adding his URL to it. Its actually pretty innovative spammer behaviour, but pretty easy to spot

I'd suggest pending dev/mod banhammerage, that users keep an eye out for posts that have a link to biospampharmacy where spam is replaced by tech, and take the appropriate flagging/editing action

Comment: Be careful. This bot sells biological spammed medications that represent risk to patients health!

Comment: Shouldn't this be on [meta.SO](http://meta.stackoverflow.com) instead? It's rather general than SU specific

Comment: Two reasons -  one of the aims of this (really old) question was to alert other SU users to the question and that sort of question, since someone had already answered it. Interestingly I've seen the same thing happen elsewhere, and totally forgot ;p.

Answer (score 5):

The user has been destroyed. While not typical spambots, I think we've seen a more 'advanced' kind of spam behaviour where the person seeds the content upon which spam answers can be fed upon.

Thanks to our ever vigilant community, a majority of the time these get nabbed and burninated. On the rare occasion such things do slip by - and given that we have the tools to minimize this, i.e., the /review route, the community does manage to spot and flag these.

That said, I'm thankful to the community for reporting and flagging these activities - helps keeping Super User squeaky clean.

My only wish would be that more users would invest about 10-15 minutes in going through  /review - it'll help us all.