# Possible spam question, how to proceed?

Tags: discussion, spam

I noticed this fishy question https://superuser.com/questions/808674/chkdsk-deleted-index-entries-now-my-file-is-gone-how-to-recover-it

- Answers seems cut-n-paste from three sources, one of them being the recommended product. Actually these are not the solutions to the problem (Answer ignores the remark that the user can't find the file)
- Link to recommended product hidden behind goo.gl
- Both 'users' registered two days ago and have no other activity

The original question could be legit although badly written

What to do?

- Edit a bad answer that was marked as correct? No way this answer is going to solve the issue.
- Write a comment to the question trying to get the OP to justify marking the answer as correct?
- Write a comment below the answer to question it?
- Write a better answer?

I searched through SU to check if it was a case of [Circumventing spam filters (and deceiving reviewers) by taking part of a legitimate post and adding a spam link--possible solutions?](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/5535/circumventing-spam-filters-and-deceiving-reviewers-by-taking-part-of-a-legitim).

Comment: It is spam for recoverytoolbox (well known spammer here). Ive flagged it. Last time the mods deleted question and answer...

Comment: The user who asked the question appears to be setting up questions for answers spamming recoverytoolbox. He is doing the same on StackOverflow. I've flagged them there as well.

Comment: The hammer has been wielded already on StackOverflow :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If something looks fishy to you, raise a flag on it. Bringing it up on meta is usually unnecessary.

The spammers have been dealt with accordingly.

Comment: `Bringing it up on meta is usually unnecessary.` +1